# no viable alternative error

Tags: antlr

I'm using ANTLR to generate recognizer for a java-like language and the following rules are used to recognize generic types:

```
referenceType
:   singleType ('.' singleType)*
;

singleType
: Identifier typeArguments?
;

typeArguments
:   '<' typeArgument (',' typeArgument)* '>' 
;

typeArgument
:    referenceType
;
```

Now, for the following input statement, ANTLR produces the 'no viable alternative' error.

```
Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
```

However, if I put a space between the two consecutive  '>' characters, no error is produced. It seams that ANTLR cannot distinguish between the above rule and the rule used to recognize shift expressions, but I don't know how to modify the grammar to resolve this ambiguity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a rule like the following in the lexer:

```
RightShift : '>>';
```

For ANTLR to recognize `>>` as either two `>` characters or one `>>` operator, depending on context, you'll need to instead place your shift operator in the parser:

```
rightShift : '>' '>';
```

If your language includes the `>>>` or `>>=` operators, those would need to be moved to the parser as well.

To validate that `x > > y` isn't allowed, you'll want to make a pass over the resulting parse tree (ANTLR 4) or AST (ANTLR 3) to verify that the two `>` characters parsed by the `rightShift` parser rule appear in sequence.

Answer (score -1):

280Z28 is probably right in his diagnosis that you have a rule like

```
RightShift : '>>';
```

An alternative solution is to explicitly include the possibility of a trailing >> in your parser.  (I have seen this in other grammars, but only in LALR.)

```
typeArguments
:   ('<' typeArgument (',' typeArgument)* '>') |
    ('<' typeArgument ',' referenceType '<' typeArgument RightShift );

;
```

In Antlr3, that will need to be left factored.

Whether this is clearer or having a second pass that validates your right shift operator depends on how often you need to use this.